# How to set darkcolor didnot set to wpfdatagrid progressbar templatecolumn?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, datatemplate, datagridtemplatecolumn

Am using the below code for showing progressbar and text,but that time am set progressbar foreground color as dark green,but while runtime it shows very very light green color,why?
How to set dark in runtime?or is it override?

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Progress" Width="*" Visibility="Visible">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Progress}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Path=Progress, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Height="25" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: I don't see any mention of color in your sample.

Comment: @nvoigt:by default the progressbar color green,but that also color also not visible

Comment: @dotNET: default color is green ,but why it visible very very light color green in runtime?